# Swift - Programmatically made contraints make image stretch

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a UIImageView and I programmatically added constraints to it. The position is right, but it stretches out my image as you can see from the screenshots...here are my constraints:

```
 let arrow = UIImageView()

 contentView.addSubview(arrow)
    arrow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    arrow.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    arrow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    arrow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    arrow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    arrow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

My question is what am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: You are setting the height as well as the top and bottom. You are probably getting an error in the console about conflicting constraints. If you want to set the height, why not set the center instead of the top and bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always necessary to give all the constrains(like leading, trailing, top, bottom, height, width, etc.) to define its size with respect to its superview.

A view just need a required constraints to set its coordinates in its super view.

As rmaddy said, Don't give excessive constraints a view.

You just need the following constants (Just remove all other constraints)

```
arrow.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
arrow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

contentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: arrow.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
arrow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

That bottom anchor causes the stretched image. You have multiple options:

1. Retain the top constraint, and remove the bottom constraint.
2. Center the imageView vertically. without top and bottom constraint of course.
3. Your code actually is correct IF you only want that imageView to determine the height of your cell (if you're using auto height). But apparently the label determines it.

Usually the views that you should connect from top to bottom are the labels or the last bottom view of your cell when using automatic cell height.

Answer (score 0):

you should add center vertically constraint and remove top and bottom anchors if you are not in need

```
   let arrow = UIImageView()
    contentView.addSubview(arrow)
    arrow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    arrow.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    arrow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    arrow.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: arrow, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([yConstraint])    //Or contentView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: arrow.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

**or if your hieght for cell is fixed**

```
 arrow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true // 25 or space your design need
 arrow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true //25 or space your design need need
```